# declaration is incompatible with .. (pointer)

Tags: c++, queue, declaration

I'm getting error on my .cpp file for this dequeue function that should return a pointer to a node
The error is : identifier Node is undefined for the return value and declaration is incompatible on
dequeue. I am wondering what I did wrong. Thanks before.

```
//quasiUniqueQ.h
#ifndef QUASIUNIQUE_H
#define QUASIUNIQUE_H
class quasiUniqueQ
{
 private:
    struct Node{
    int value;
    int age;
    };

    Node* array;
    int size;
    int top;

void resize();
void copy(); // wrong return value;
void aging();


     public:
 void operator=(const quasiUniqueQ& rhs);
 quasiUniqueQ(int num = 50);
 ~quasiUniqueQ();
 void enqueue(int newNum);
 Node* dequeue();
 bool isEmpty();
 bool isFull();


    };
 #endif



//quasiUniqueQ.cpp

#include "quasiUniqueQ.h"

using namespace std;

Node* quasiUniqueQ::dequeue() //ERROR HERE
{


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `Node` is declared inside `quasiUnuqieQ`, so you would need

```
quasiUniqueQ::Node* quasiUniqueQ::dequeue() { ... }
```

However, you are limited in what you can do with it outside `quasiUniqueQ`, because `Node` has been declared as `private`, so you cannot declare a `quasiuniqueQ::Node` or `quasiUniqueQ::Node*` to assign to the return of a call to `quasiUniqueQ::dequeue()`, and since you cannot name `quasuUniqueQ::Node` outside the class, you would be forced to define the member function inside the class:

```
struct quasiUniqueQ
{
   ...
  Node* dequeue() { return .... ; }
};
```

Then, you could in principle call the method, with some limitations:

```
quasiUnuqueQ q;
q.dequeue(); // Compiles, but is useless
quasiUniqueQ::Node* n = q.dequeue(); // Error, quasiUnuqueQ::Node is private.
auto n = q.dequeue(); // OK
```

Comment: That was thorough and informational. Very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a member that returns a type with a narrower access modifier.  In this case, the `Node` struct is *private* to your class, but you attempt to return a pointer to a `Node` object from a *public* member.  Because it is private, the `Node` type cannot be used outside of your class, so it is not possible to return anything typed as `Node` from a public member.

You also need to fully specify the name of the struct, since the type is contained within your class, but you are defining the method *outside* of your class:

```
quasiUniqueQ::Node* quasiUniqueQ::dequeue()
{

}
```

Comment: since it is within the same class, I thought they would be accessible. I do not have any error now but I actually thought public functions can access and return private members as long as they are from the same class. Thank you.

Comment: @LeonardLie They can return private *members* but not private *types*.  How would code external to this class use data of a type that is private to another class?